# aspnet razor editorfor conditionally add attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

I'm using the following approach to create form controls:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FK_CompID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly"})
```

but when I need to make it conditionally whether it be read only or not I shall remove that attribute,

Is there any way to handle it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FK_CompID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = null})
```

and should be not added to element?

Comment: You need to show us what is the property that determines the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build an object defining the html attributes based on some property and then use that in the `DropDownList()` method. Assuming you model contains a property `bool IsReadOnly`, then

```
@{
    var attributes = Model.IsReadOnly ? 
    (object)new { @class = "form-control", readonly = "readonly" } :
    (object)new { @class = "form-control"};
}
@Html.DropDownList("FK_CompID", null, attributes)
```

Comment: Trying this with an `@Html.EditorFor()` and it just plain doesn't want to work. :(

Comment: @ScottK.Fraley, Ask a new question (and `EditorFor()` does not have an overload that accepts html attributes unless your using MVC-5.1 or higher, and then its a different syntax.

Comment: Well actually, I switched to `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TaxPayer, attributes)` and it's working great! Now if I could just get `@Html.TextBoxFor()` to render my dang Prompt/placeholder as specified in the `DisplayAttribute` I'd be all set!

Comment: @ScottK.Fraley, The `[Display]` attribute is used for generating a label associated with a control. It has nothing at all to do with a 'prompt/placeholder`

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using @Html.EditorFor() and htmlAttributes.

You can set HTML Attributes as below

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.item, new { name ="name", htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

This worked for me to set a sortable table to have the editor fields read only.